# Current activity will refresh when the firebase updates its data

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Here I have used my main activity with four fragments as below.

```
navigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new ChipNavigationBar.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(int id) {
        Fragment fragment=null;
        switch (id){
            case R.id.bottom_nav_Home:
                fragment=new HomeFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.bottom_nav_Chats:

                   fragment=new ChatFragment();
                    break;



            case R.id.bottom_nav_Users:
                fragment=new UsersFragment();
                break;


            case R.id.bottom_nav_Profile:
                fragment=new ProfileFragment();
                break;
        }

        if(fragment !=null){
          fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
          fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                  .replace(R.id.content,fragment)
                  .commit();
        }
        else{
            Log.e(TAG,"Error");
        }
    }
});
```

In profile fragment I have initiated a switch and when it is checked it is updating the firebase data as follows.

```
private void updatemylocationastrue() {
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("location", "true");
DatabaseReference ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
ref.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).updateChildren(map)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You have turned on your location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

            }
        });
    }
```

The method and fragment works fine. But when firebase updates, suddenly it automatically restart the activity and navigate it to default home fragment. But I need to stay in the same profile fragment. How to improve this code?

Comment: Most likely your crashes. If so, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: @AlexMamo No any error in the logcat. I Check that.Firebase also updates

Comment: Try removing Toast message onSuccess. Because it may be an error of getContext()

Comment: @RealTechHacks didnt work that.

Comment: Have you seen your logcat for errors?

Comment: Do you set any event listener in same activity to fetch user's data?